# How to access a VBA array element that was returned from a COM call?

Tags: vba, excel, com

In the code below the line

```
'ActiveCell.Value = nextToGoRacesValue.races(0).raceName
```

Gives error, sub index out of range, but there are at least 35 elements in the array that was returned, is accessing them as variants the only way?

Is there anythng specific to COM arrays that I should be aware of?

```
Dim nextToGoRaces As New TABV1_NextToGoRaces
Dim nextToGoRacesValue As NextToGoRacesValue
Set nextToGoRacesValue = nextToGoRaces.GetValues()

'ActiveCell.Value = nextToGoRacesValue.races(0).raceName    

Dim element As Variant    
    For Each element In nextToGoRacesValue.races
        ActiveCell.Value = element.raceName    
    Next element
```

Comment: @Jelly sub index out of range, what's difference between jelly and Jam?

Comment: fantastic! That means that .races (obviously a collection of some type) contains no elements. Eg: There are no reces in the nextTgoRacesValues to traverse. If that's the expected behavior then you might want to handle that with if condition, if not (meaning that are races to be traversed) can you share the class code so we can dig into it?

Comment: In the watch there are elements in it! when I use the variant syntax can access all the elements.maybe just convert it t array of TypedItes using the for each and vriant intead, thanks fr the idea.

Comment: Tell me if that works for you?

Comment: @Jelly Will do, it is strange that acessing the array element 0 or 1 causes error, but turning them into variants works!

Comment: variant magic my dawg  ^ _ ^

Comment: That would suggest that the returned data is *not an array* but a Collection as @Jelly said.

Comment: @Rory Holly hell, they were defined as array in the C# COM library! Intresting

Comment: @Rory but that still doesnt explain why accessing a cllectin member by index desnt wrk either, the array and collection index access are exactlt loking the same, what is the difference?

Comment: @Arjang I shouldn't really have capitalised the word `collection`. It may not be a VBA `Collection` but some custom object which simply doesn't allow accessing via index number. What's the declaration in the COM library exactly?

Comment: @Rory : The object browser shews it as Races(), C# Code is Races[]

Comment: I think this miight be the reason https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264711.aspx

Comment: As a matter of interest, does this work: `ActiveCell.Value = nextToGoRacesValue.races()(0).raceName`, or using 1 rather than 0?

Comment: @Rory : Excellent idea, yes I will try that when I get back t work, will let you know

Comment: Can you share the definition of races with us?

Comment: @Jelly Yes, I will, I go back to work in 10 hours

Comment: I'll be off work in 3 hours yey lol

Comment: @Arjang: oh btw jelly is me jam is my cousin lol 
ps: Who are you?